# how to stop skrollr while scrolling up

Tags: jquery, jquery-waypoints, skrollr

im wrecking my head over skrollr issue since last 3 days and some idiot thought that its a marketing gimmick
I want to stop the skrollr plugin when i scroll upto the bottom. while scrolling up it should not do anything. I mean it should not reverse the animation

this is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/eq3u9/1/

```
<div style="height:600px; background-color:#960" data-0="opacity:0;" data-100="opacity:1;">scroll down</div>
```

Just to know I have integrated waypoint js also into this project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
skrollr.init({
    beforerender: function(data) {
        return data.direction == 'down';
    }
});
```

Answer (score 8):

```
skrollr.init({
    beforerender: function(data) {
        return data.curTop > data.lastTop;
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eq3u9/2/

Comment: I turned it into a one-liner.

Comment: Is there any way to do this for some elements but not others?